# eth_call swapExactTokensForETH simulation error

Tags: transactions, uniswap, python, erc-20-approve, eth-call

I can do swapExactEthForTokens with no issue but when I try to do the reverse, swapExactTokensForETH, I run into this error:

```
{
    "name": "ContractLogicError",
    "message": "execution reverted: revert: TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED",
    "stack": "---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ContractLogicError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[101], line 33
     24 print(f'txn_hash_{txn_hash}')
     26 # Step 3: Construct the swapExactTokensForETH transaction
     27 txn = contract.functions.swapExactTokensForETH(
     28     input_token_amount_sell,
     29     amount_out_min_buy,
     30     path,
     31     to_address,
     32     deadline
---> 33 ).build_transaction({
     34     'from': seller_address,
     35     'gasPrice': w3.eth.gas_price
     36 })
     38 print(txn)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/web3/contract.py:1279, in ContractFunction.build_transaction(self, transaction)
   1276 def build_transaction(self, transaction: Optional[TxParams] = None) -> TxParams:
   1278     built_transaction = self._build_transaction(transaction)
-> 1279     return build_transaction_for_function(
   1280         self.address,
   1281         self.w3,
   1282         self.function_identifier,
   1283         built_transaction,
   1284         self.contract_abi,
   1285         self.abi,
   1286         *self.args,
   1287         **self.kwargs,
   1288     )

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/web3/contract.py:2320, in build_transaction_for_function(address, w3, function_name, transaction, contract_abi, fn_abi, *args, **kwargs)
   2304 \"\"\"Builds a dictionary with the fields required to make the given transaction
   2305 
   2306 Don't call this directly, instead use :meth:`Contract.build_transaction`
   2307 on your contract instance.
   2308 \"\"\"
   2309 prepared_transaction = prepare_transaction(
   2310     address,
   2311     w3,
   (...)
   2317     fn_kwargs=kwargs,
   2318 )
-> 2320 prepared_transaction = fill_transaction_defaults(w3, prepared_transaction)
   2322 return prepared_transaction

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cytoolz/functoolz.pyx:249, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__()

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/web3/_utils/transactions.py:128, in fill_transaction_defaults(w3, transaction)
    124     if w3 is None:
    125         raise ValueError(
    126             f\"You must specify a '{key}' value in the transaction\"
    127         )
--> 128     default_val = default_getter(w3, transaction)
    129 else:
    130     default_val = default_getter

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/web3/_utils/transactions.py:71, in <lambda>(w3, tx)
     38 TX_PARAM_LITERALS = Literal[
     39     \"type\",
     40     \"from\",
   (...)
     50     \"accessList\",
     51 ]
     53 VALID_TRANSACTION_PARAMS: List[TX_PARAM_LITERALS] = [
     54     \"type\",
     55     \"from\",
   (...)
     65     \"chainId\",
     66 ]
     68 TRANSACTION_DEFAULTS = {
     69     \"value\": 0,
     70     \"data\": b\"\",
---> 71     \"gas\": lambda w3, tx: w3.eth.estimate_gas(tx),
     72     \"gasPrice\": lambda w3, tx: w3.eth.generate_gas_price(tx),
     73     \"maxFeePerGas\": (
     74         lambda w3, tx: w3.eth.max_priority_fee
     75         + (2 * w3.eth.get_block(\"latest\")[\"baseFeePerGas\"])
     76     ),
     77     \"maxPriorityFeePerGas\": lambda w3, tx: w3.eth.max_priority_fee,
     78     \"chainId\": lambda w3, tx: w3.eth.chain_id,
     79 }
     81 if TYPE_CHECKING:
     82     from web3 import Web3  # noqa: F401

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/web3/eth.py:895, in Eth.estimate_gas(self, transaction, block_identifier)
    892 def estimate_gas(
    893     self, transaction: TxParams, block_identifier: Optional[BlockIdentifier] = None
    894 ) -> int:
--> 895     return self._estimate_gas(transaction, block_identifier)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/web3/module.py:64, in retrieve_blocking_method_call_fn.<locals>.caller(*args, **kwargs)
     58     return LogFilter(eth_module=module, filter_id=err.filter_id)
     59 (
     60     result_formatters,
     61     error_formatters,
     62     null_result_formatters,
     63 ) = response_formatters
---> 64 result = w3.manager.request_blocking(
     65     method_str, params, error_formatters, null_result_formatters
     66 )
     67 return apply_result_formatters(result_formatters, result)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/web3/manager.py:199, in RequestManager.request_blocking(self, method, params, error_formatters, null_result_formatters)
    195 \"\"\"
    196 Make a synchronous request using the provider
    197 \"\"\"
    198 response = self._make_request(method, params)
--> 199 return self.formatted_response(
    200     response, params, error_formatters, null_result_formatters
    201 )

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/web3/manager.py:171, in RequestManager.formatted_response(response, params, error_formatters, null_result_formatters)
    163 @staticmethod
    164 def formatted_response(
    165     response: RPCResponse,
   (...)
    168     null_result_formatters: Optional[Callable[..., Any]] = None,
    169 ) -> Any:
    170     if \"error\" in response:
--> 171         apply_error_formatters(error_formatters, response)
    172         raise ValueError(response[\"error\"])
    173     # NULL_RESPONSES includes None, so return False here as the default
    174     # so we don't apply the null_result_formatters if there is no 'result' key

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/web3/manager.py:74, in apply_error_formatters(error_formatters, response)
     69 def apply_error_formatters(
     70     error_formatters: Callable[..., Any],
     71     response: RPCResponse,
     72 ) -> RPCResponse:
     73     if error_formatters:
---> 74         formatted_resp = pipe(response, error_formatters)
     75         return formatted_resp
     76     else:

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cytoolz/functoolz.pyx:666, in cytoolz.functoolz.pipe()

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cytoolz/functoolz.pyx:641, in cytoolz.functoolz.c_pipe()

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/web3/_utils/method_formatters.py:636, in raise_contract_logic_error_on_revert(response)
    634 # Geth case:
    635 if \"message\" in response[\"error\"] and response[\"error\"].get(\"code\", \"\") == 3:
--> 636     raise ContractLogicError(response[\"error\"][\"message\"])
    638 # Geth Revert without error message case:
    639 if \"execution reverted\" in response[\"error\"].get(\"message\"):

ContractLogicError: execution reverted: revert: TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED"
}
```

what am I doing wrong? I even have the approval before there but do I add that to the txn somehow? I'm using the uniswap v2 router and have the abi, contract address, etc.

```
def approve_token_transfer(token_contract, amount: int, spender_address: str, user_address: str) -> str:
    token_abi = get_verified_contract_etherscan(token_contract).get('result')[0].get('ABI')
    contract = w3.eth.contract(address=w3.to_checksum_address(token_contract), abi=token_abi)
    txn_result = contract.functions.approve(spender_address, amount).call({'from': w3.to_checksum_address(user_address)})
    return txn_result

seller_address = w3.to_checksum_address('some random address')
to_address = uniswap_v2_router_contract_address
deadline = int(time.time()) + (20 * 60)  # 20 minutes from now

amount_out_min_buy = 2083.275609858082
print(f'amount out min buy: {output_weth_amount_sell / 1e18}')
path = path_sell

txn_hash = approve_token_transfer(token_contract=token_address, amount=amount_out_min_buy, spender_address=uniswap_v2_router_contract_address, user_address=seller_address)
print(f'txn_hash_{txn_hash}')

txn = contract.functions.swapExactTokensForETH(
    input_token_amount_sell,
    amount_out_min_buy,
    path,
    to_address,
    deadline
).build_transaction({
    'from': seller_address,
    'gasPrice': w3.eth.gas_price
})

print(txn)
```

Comment: does token have some fee on transfer? If so, try using swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens

Comment: @0xSanson no, it has no transfer fee